# JavaScript client object model - get current user email id, first name, last name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, csom

I want to understand the difference between the following two methods to retrieve the current user email id:

**Method 1:**

```
function getCurrentUserEmail(){
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.website = clientContext.get_web();
  this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
  clientContext.load(currentUser);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestFail));
}
function onRequestSuccess(sender, args){
  var curUserEmail = currentUser.get_email();
}
function onRequestFail(sender, args){
  alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
function getCurrentUserEmail(){
  var targetUser = "domainName\\Username"; //logged in user
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
  personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);
  clientContext.load(personProperties);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestFail));
}
function onRequestSuccess(sender, args){
  var strEmailID = personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['WorkEmail'];
  var strLastName = personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['FirstName'];
  var strEmailID = personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['LastName'];
}
function onRequestFail(sender, args){
  alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

With the first method I can only get UserID, Email, LoginName and Title, but the second method is required to get first name & last name fields.


The problem is, that both methods are working fine in my local environment, but **Method 2** is not working in the production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the other way of getting current user info

```
function getCurrentUserEmail(){
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.website = clientContext.get_web();
  this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
  clientContext.load(currentUser);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestFail));
}
function onRequestSuccess(sender, args){
  var curUserEmail = currentUser.get_email();
  var curUserloginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
  getUserInfo(curUserloginName);
}
function onRequestFail(sender, args){
  alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
function getUserInfo(loginName){
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var userInfoList = context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();
  var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
  var viewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + loginName+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
  query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
  var items = userInfoList.getItems(query);
  context.load(items,'Include(Deleted,Department,EMail,FirstName,ID,IsActive,IsSiteAdmin,JobTitle,LastName,MobilePhone,Name,Notes,Office,Picture,SipAddress,UserName,WebSite,WorkPhone)');
  context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    if(items.get_count() > 0) {
      var item = items.itemAt(0);
      console.log('User Id: ' + item.ID);
      console.log('First Name: ' + item.FirstName);
      console.log('Last Name: ' + item.LastName);
      console.log('EMail: ' + item.EMail);
      console.log('Name: ' + item.Name);
      console.log('User Name: ' + item.UserName);
    }
  },
    console.log(args.get_message());
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to access the `PeopleManager` you need to load `SP.UserProfiles.js` so this line on the top of method two.

```
 SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getCurrentUserEmail, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
```

You can additionally use fiddler and IE/Chrome developer tools to check if scripts are loaded properly.

Comment: still it is going to requestFail method with error message like -- "Unknown Error, Undefined"

Comment: How are you accessing it? App, web part or what? what JS script files are loading in the chrome/IE at the time of error? Could you paste the screen shot?

Comment: I am using it in a site page with inside a <script> block and calling the methods on click of two buttons.
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
Like this I am using sp.js, sp.runtime.js, sp.core.js, SP.UserProfiles.js