# Get Email Address from PeoplePicker field using JavaScript Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I'm getting lookupValue and lookupId from people picker filed from SharePoint list using jsom. Now I need Email address by using lookupvalue/lookupId.

Here is my code

```
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
 var ProjectManager=listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('ProjectManager');
 var ManagerName = ProjectManager.get_lookupValue();
 var ManagerId = ProjectManager.get_lookupId();
}
```

Comment: Please look into it...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146717/javascript-client-object-model-get-current-user-email-id-first-name-last-nam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get everything of a user from it's `id`. Like following

```
function getEmail(userId) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext("https://xxx.sharepoint.com");
    var web = context.get_web();
    var user = web.get_siteUsers().getById(userId);
    context.load(user);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        console.log(user.get_email());
    }, function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

List of user properties can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser_properties(v=office.14).aspx).